# Moai: Graphics that reacts to commands via Sockets

Tags: sockets, lua, luasocket, moai

I need a program that can create pre-defined shapes on screen according to that commands I send to it via TCP. 
I'm trying to listen to a port and so that I can use them. Before waiting of a command (via network) I have the commands required to create a square (I plan to change its attributes via network commands)

The problem is it is not creating any graphics or opening the window as it should be..

```
require "socket"
require "mime"
require "ltn12"

host = "localhost"
port = "8080"
server, error = socket.bind(host, port)
if not server then print("server: " .. tostring(error)) os.exit() end


screen=MOAISim.openWindow ( "test", 640, 640 )

viewport = MOAIViewport.new (screen)
viewport:setSize ( 640, 640 )
viewport:setScale ( 640, 640 )

layer = MOAILayer2D.new ()
layer:setViewport ( viewport )
MOAISim.pushRenderPass ( layer )

function fillSquare (x,y,radius,red,green,blue)
a = red/255
b = green/255
c = blue/255
MOAIGfxDevice.setPenColor ( a, b, c) -- green
MOAIGfxDevice.setPenWidth ( 2 )
MOAIDraw.fillCircle ( x, y, radius, 4 ) -- x,y,r,steps
end
function onDraw (  )

fillSquare(0,64,64, 0,0,255)
end

scriptDeck = MOAIScriptDeck.new ()
scriptDeck:setRect ( -64, -64, 64, 64 )
scriptDeck:setDrawCallback (    onDraw)


prop = MOAIProp2D.new ()
prop:setDeck ( scriptDeck )
layer:insertProp ( prop )


while 1 do
   print("server: waiting for client command...")
   control = server:accept()
    command, error = control:receive()
    print(command,error)
    error = control:send("hi from Moai\n")

end
```

It is waiting of the command from client at control = server:accept() but it is not opening up the graphics window as it should.. Is there any command to force it to open or render

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOAI doesn't run your scripts in a separate thread. A blocking call (`server:accept`) or forever loop (`while true do`) will block your MOAI app and it will appear to freeze while it merrily sits in your script forever.

So you have to do two things:

1. Use non-blocking calls. In this case, you need to set your server's timeout to 0. That makes `server:accept` return immediately. Check it's return value to see if you got a connection.
2. Put your while loop in a coroutine and yield once per iteration.

You'll need to handle the client the same way, using non-blocking calls in a coroutine loop.

```
function clientProc(client)
  print('client connected:', client)

  client:settimeout(0) -- make client socket reads non-blocking

  while true do
    local command, err = client:receive('*l')
    if command then 
      print('received command:', command) 
      err = client:send("hi from Moai\n")
    elseif err == 'closed' then
      print('client disconnected:', client)
      break
    elseif err ~= 'timeout' then
      print('error: ', err)
      break
    end
    coroutine.yield()
  end
  client:close()
end

function serverProc()
    print("server: waiting for client connections...")

    server:settimeout(0) -- make server:accept call non-blocking

    while true do
        local client = server:accept()
        if client then
            MOAICoroutine.new():run(clientProc, client)
        end
        coroutine.yield()
    end
end

MOAICoroutine.new():run(serverProc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the timeout for the server socket, since the accept is a blocking call.

```
server:settimeout(1)
```

Comment: His while loop will stop block MOAI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mud...I found that before u replied so the following coroutine works

```
function threadFunc()
    local action
    while 1 do

    stat, control = server:accept()
    --print(control,stat)
    while 1 do
        if stat then
            command, error = stat:receive()
            print("Comm: ", command, error)
            if command then

                stat:close()
                print("server: closing connection...")
                break
            else
                break
            end
            --[[
          error = stat:send("hi")
          if error then
              stat:close()
              print("server: closing connection...",error)
              break
          end  ]] --
        else
            break
        end

    end
    coroutine.yield()
end
end
```

That was very helpful though